# Command at ExecStart in Ubuntu service fails, but works when maually executed

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, systemd

I a'm trying to execute the following `/usr/local/sbin/namespaced-openvpn --config /home/sb/vpn/static2.ovpn --writepid /var/run/openvpn-protected-foo-sb.pid --log /var/log/openvpn-protected-foo-sb.log --daemon` using the following: [namespeced-openvpn](https://github.com/slingamn/namespaced-openvpn)

When i run this command and I check the log file, everything is up and running correctly

Now I want to execute this command right before rtorrent is started, and then run rtorrent with that tunnel. I have rtorrent installed from [swizzin](https://github.com/swizzin/swizzin) and a service file has been created for me. I a'm no expert, but I try to edit this file to achieve this, and have the following in `/etc/systemd/system/rtorrent@.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=rTorrent
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
KillMode=none
User=%i
ExecStartPre=-/bin/rm -f /home/sb/.sessions/rtorrent.lock
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/namespaced-openvpn --config /home/sb/vpn/static2.ovpn --writepid /var/run/openvpn-protected-foo-sb.pid --log /var/log/openvpn-protected-foo-sb.log --daemon && /usr/bin/screen -L -Logfile /home/sb/screen.log -S rtorrent -d -m bash -c "ip netns exec protected sudo -u sb /usr/bin/rtorrent"
ExecStop=/usr/bin/screen -X -S rtorrent quit && sudo pkill -F /var/run/openvpn-protected-foo-sb.pid
WorkingDirectory=/home/sb/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I ran `systemctl daemon-reload`, stoped/disabled the default rtorrent@DEFAULTUSER and instead enabled rtorrent@root, and rebooted. Efter reboot runing `systemctl status rtorrent@root` gives me:

```
● rtorrent@root.service - rTorrent
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rtorrent@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-09-03 18:11:54 UTC; 20min ago
    Process: 720 ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /home/sb/.sessions/rtorrent.lock (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 744 ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/namespaced-openvpn --config /home/sb/vpn/static2.ovpn --writepid /var/run/openvpn-protected-foo-sb.pid --log /var/log/openvpn-protected-foo-sb.log --daemon && /u>

Sep 03 18:11:49 seedbox systemd[1]: Starting rTorrent...
Sep 03 18:11:54 seedbox systemd[1]: rtorrent@root.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 03 18:11:54 seedbox systemd[1]: rtorrent@root.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 03 18:11:54 seedbox systemd[1]: Failed to start rTorrent.
```

And the logfile from namespaced-openvpn command `cat /var/log/openvpn-protected-foo-sb.log`

```
Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [CMD-LINE]:1: daemon (2.4.7)
Use --help for more information.
```

A'm I doing something wrong here? Any help would be much appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that you can't do &&, because the command is not executed in a shell. To make it work I could do something like this `ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'COMMAND1 && COMMAND2'` or I could use multiple `ExecStartPre` so the file now looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=rTorrent
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
KillMode=none
User=%i
ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /home/sb/.sessions/rtorrent.lock
ExecStartPre=/usr/local/sbin/namespaced-openvpn --config /home/sb/vpn/static2.ovpn --writepid /var/run/openvpn-protected-foo-sb.pid --log /var/log/openvpn-protected-foo-sb.log --daemon
ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -L -Logfile /home/sb/screen.log -S rtorrent -d -m bash -c "ip netns exec protected sudo -u sb /usr/bin/rtorrent"
ExecStop=/usr/bin/screen -X -S rtorrent quit
ExecStop=pkill -F /var/run/openvpn-protected-foo-sb.pid
WorkingDirectory=/home/sb/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```